# Spring MVC form giving HTTP Status 400

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am getting HTTP status 400. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. What I am doing is, just saving edit form into database, but request not going to `saveApplication` method.

The following is my `edit.jsp`:

```
<div align="center">
        <h1>New/Edit Contact</h1>
        <form:form action="saveApplication" method="post" modelAttribute="application">
        <table>
            <form:hidden path="applicationId"/>
            <tr>
                <td>Application Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="applicationName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Start Date:</td>
                <td><form:input path="startDate" id="startDate"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Date:</td>
                <td><form:input path="endDate" id="endDate"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Projected StartDate:</td>
                <td><form:input path="projectedStartDate" id="projectedStartDate"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Projected EndDate:</td>
                <td><form:input path="projectedEndDate" id="projectedEndDate"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Current Action:</td>
                <td><form:input path="currentAction" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Comments:</td>
                <td><form:input path="comments" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
```

The following are methods in my controller class:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editApplication", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editApplication(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        int applicationId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        ApplicationTO to = applicationService.getApplication(applicationId);
        model.addObject("application", to);
        model.setViewName("edit");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveApplication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute ApplicationTO application) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        applicationService.saveApplication(application);
        model.setViewName("view");
        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have Missed the variable danoneValidation in the form, actually this variable present in Model class.

```
   <div align="center">
            <h1>New/Edit Contact</h1>
            <form:form action="saveApplication" method="post" modelAttribute="application">
            <table>
                <form:hidden path="applicationId"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>Application Name:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="applicationName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Start Date:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="startDate" id="startDate"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>End Date:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="endDate" id="endDate"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Projected StartDate:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="projectedStartDate" id="projectedStartDate"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Projected EndDate:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="projectedEndDate" id="projectedEndDate"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Current Action:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="currentAction" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Danone Validation:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="danoneValidation" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Comments:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="comments" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form:form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put a slash before the action name something like

```
<form:form action="/saveApplication" method="post" modelAttribute="application"> <table>
```

This is might be required.

Also check which is the URL that is printed on the browser bar when you submit the form. Double check that the path is what your controller is expecting.

Comment: I have tried above one, its     giving HTTP Status 404 - /saveApplication

Comment: its giving theurl like this when i submit http://localhost:8080/saveApplication (for the above solution) and its  not showing any logs

Comment: Spring uses strong naming convention... Can you try inside of the controller instead of application use applicationId as in the form?

Comment: Check this tutorial... It may be helpfull http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hidden-value-example/

Comment: Thanks @OEH i have missed to add a input label that is available in model class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137227/discussion-between-asr-and-oeh).